# Build Failed for SSIS Solution in VS2017

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

We have our SSIS solution up and running in VS2012, and we wannt to migrate to VS2017. But when we open the solution and do a build on VS2017 (Version - 15.9.14), the build failed with the below error message.

Current version running and built successfully in VS2012. Details are as follows:

VS2012 - 11.0.50727.1
SSDT - 11.1.20627.00
SQL Server Integration Services - 11.0.5583.0

New version of Visual studio where its failing as below:

VS2017 - 15.9.14
SSDT - 15.1.61906.0.3120
SQL Server Integration Services - 15.0.1301.433

How to fix this build issue on the new version of VS2017?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.LoadPackageFromXML(Object vSource, Boolean vbSourceIsLocation, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.LoadPackage(IProjectStorage storage, Package package, String streamName, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)           0
```

Comment: [Make sure that all packages are upgraded successfully](https://www.hansmichiels.com/2016/10/23/how-to-upgrade-your-ssis-packages-from-sql-server-2012-to-2016-ssis-series/)

Comment: @Hadi, but my upgrade all package window shows no ssis packages to be selected to upgrade. Not sure why.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue, by opening the individual dtsx package in edit mode and moved the below tag in the xml from bottom to line no:3 in the xml

`<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</DTS:Property>` 

After which the build went successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, by opening the individual dtsx package in edit mode and moved the below tag in the xml from bottom to line no:3 in the xml and save it.

`<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</DTS:Property>`

After which the re-build went successful without any errors.